# Montana special House election: when will the winner take office?

Tags: united-states, election, congress, house-of-representatives

A [special election](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montana%27s_at-large_congressional_district_special_election,_2017) is being held in Montana on May 25 to fill a vacant seat in the House of Representatives.

On what date would the winner take office?

I haven't seen this information in any news articles about the election.

Answer (score 3):

The winner will take office once the vote is certified, according to Montana's state law.

> (4) (a) (i) The governor may make a temporary appointment to fill a vacancy until the election to fill the vacancy is held.
>
> (ii) (A) If the vacancy is subject to the provisions of subsection (3)(b), the governor may make a temporary appointment **until the results of the regularly scheduled general election are certified**.
>
> *(emphasis mine)*
>
> Source: http://leg.mt.gov/bills/mca/13/25/13-25-203.htm

Comment: That's definitely the relevant section of law, but I'm not sure if you quoted the right section. It's not between the primary and general election, and it's not an even numbered year.

Comment: No, he won't.   The House GOP leadership will face a dilemma about whether to use its constitutional powers to refuse to seat Gianforte.  Then and only then will he assume his seat in the House

Comment: @KDog Do you have a source that states that?

Comment: Article 1, Section 5. Section 5.
Each House shall be the judge of the elections, returns and qualifications of its own members, and a majority of each shall constitute a quorum to do business; but a smaller number may adjourn from day to day, and may be authorized to compel the attendance of absent members, in such manner, and under such penalties as each House may provide.

Comment: Basically, the House could disqualify him for the body slamming incident.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unseated_members_of_the_United_States_Congress

Comment: @KDog Thanks! I didn't see the news when I answered this question so ...

Comment: You're welcome.  As for the exact timing, it's after the Speaker gives the oath of office, if the House is so inclined based upon the above.

Comment: Also note that the Powell discussion in Wikipedia is off as way too absolute